# Why is this equality true: $f(w) = f (\sqrt w)\frac{d(\sqrt w)}{dw}$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to understand a new chapter in Mathematical Statistics with Applications 7th Edition
by Dennis Wackerly, William Mendenhall, Richard L. Scheaffer.

In Example 9.7 I don't understand why a specific equality is true  $f(w) = f (\sqrt w)\frac{d(\sqrt w)}{dw}$ when proving that it is an exponential distribution.
I'm including the whole exercise:

First part of exercise:

[image]

Second part of exercise including the unclear equality:

[image]

Can someone please explain this one equality, everything else seems clear to me.
Thank you!

Comment: The equality you are asking about is due to [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar).

Comment: What you wrote is not what is in the picture.  You have $f$ twice where the picture has $f_W$ and $f$.

Comment: Does the link above answer your question?